# Failing to submit to a link page

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

When i click on the submit button i am getting the 404 error, i want to submit to the "new_search"

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

    <form action="{ % url 'new_search' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="search" value="search" placeholder="search">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>


{% endblock content %}
```

page

Comment: Press F12 and look in the network tab for the URL it tries to access and fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in your code, replace:

```
{ % url 'new_search' %}
```

with

```
{% url 'new_search' %}
```